# I lost national signs after OS update

Tags: command-line, server, fonts, localization

I have home server with **Ubuntu Server 20.04**. I used to have fonts with polish signs in console. But after some OS update I notice that I have some quirks in the places expected to have polish signs.

How can I restore polish fonts in **Ubuntu Server 20.04** console?

---

Thanks for suggestions!

I try `setupcon`:

```
$ sudo setupcon -v
Configuring /dev/tty1 /dev/tty2 /dev/tty3 /dev/tty4 /dev/tty5 /dev/tty6
The charmap is UTF-8
BackSpace is ^?
on /dev/tty1  executing printf.
on /dev/tty2  executing printf.
on /dev/tty3  executing printf.
on /dev/tty4  executing printf.
on /dev/tty5  executing printf.
on /dev/tty6  executing printf.
on /dev/tty1  executing kbd_mode -u.
on /dev/tty2  executing kbd_mode -u.
on /dev/tty3  executing kbd_mode -u.
on /dev/tty4  executing kbd_mode -u.
on /dev/tty5  executing kbd_mode -u.
on /dev/tty6  executing kbd_mode -u.
executing loadkeys /etc/console-setup/cached_UTF-8_del.kmap.gz.
```

but I think it does not touch consol font.

So I try setfont:

```
$ sudo setfont
Nie można znaleźć domyślnego fontu
```

[Please ignoere polish signs for a while.]
Then I read `man setfont` and found that there is missing `/usr/share/consolefonts/default.psf.gz` file.
Then I linked

```
$sudo ln -s /usr/share/consolefonts/Lat2-TerminusBold16.psf.gz /usr/share/consolefonts/default.psf.gz
```

And then run again:

```
$ sudo setfont -v
Wczytywanie 256-znakowego fontu 8x16 z pliku /usr/share/consolefonts/default.psf.gz
Wczytywanie tablicy odwzorowania Unicode...
```

I realy enjoy because I have polish signs, but only till logout.

So, now the question is: How make my font config persistent? And in "Ubuntu way".

Comment: Run `setupcon`.

Comment: This is just a workaround, but you could put the commands that makes this work, so probably the last codeblock, the one with `sudo setfont -v` into the end of this file: `~/.profile`. This file is being read every time you log in, and commands in it will be executed automatically.

Comment: I supose it will work, but i want configure console "in ubuntu way". So please give me more comprehensive advice.

Answer (score 0):

1. Update the console font configuration:

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
   ```
2. Select the correct keyboard layout and language.
3. Restart the terminal emulator or log out and log back in.